# Prove $X$ is uncountable if $X$ is the set of all functions $f: \mathbb{Z}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_+$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm not sure how to approach this. I've seen a proof how to prove that $[0,1]$ is uncountable. I thought of doing this by contradiction, and assuming that $X$ was countable, but I can't really go anywhere with it.

How would I approach this?

Comment: Hint: given a real number $x = 0.x_1x_2x_3\dots \in (0,1]$, define $f_x$ by $f_x(n) = x_n.$

Comment: @BaronVT: For $\frac12$ do you define $f_{\frac12}(1)=5$ and the rest $0$; or do you define $f_{\frac12}(1)=4$ and the rest $9$?

Comment: Also, the powerset of $\mathbb{Z}_+$ is a subset of your set and is clearly uncountable, if you know some set theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  Good point, a full solution should probably take this into account

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: initially, the OP defined $X$ as the set of functions from $\mathbb{Z}_+$ to itself.

Suppose that $X$ is countable so that we can enumerate $X$ as $f_1,f_2,\ldots$ Now consider a function $f_0$ defined as $f_0(n)=f_n(n)+1$. Then, $f_0$ is clearly an element of $X$ and $f_0$ differs from $f_n$ for all $n>0$. But this is a contradiction because we have assumed that we can completely enumerate $X$ as $\{f_1,f_2,f_3,\ldots\}$.

If $X$ is the set of functions from $\mathbb{Z}_+$ to $\{0,1\}$, then the above argument still works with a slight modification: $f_0(n)=1-f_n(n)$.